# Postman datadriven tests

Tags: postman, schema, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

We are doing some assertion checks in Postman. For doing so, we created a collection which is having set of Api's . Now, in order to perform data driven tests , we created a excel file.
Here comes an issue when we run the collection through excel . All the Api's in that collection is running for same number of iteration. Is there any way by which we can control the execution run for different api's that exist in that particular collection.